# Hide maintain page when a user is "end user" in ORACLE APEX

Tags: oracle, authentication, oracle-apex, admin, end-user

I want to hide Maintain pages from and set regulations on "end user"
I'm creating application in oracle apex. For now I have 2 users accounts: One is administrator named A, the one is end user named B. Administrator can edit, insert and delete data but end user can not do that. The thing end user can do is just to see the data.

For now both can see all pages and end user can do everything. How can archive it? I found the information about Authentication scheme, which may be related to my question. But I do not know how to write it. Please suggest solutions.

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is to create a function which says whether certain user is *end user*. For example:

```
create table users
  (username   varchar2(30),
   user_role  varchar2(20)
  );

insert into users (username, user_role)
  select 'Little', 'Admin'   from dual union all
  select 'Foot'  , 'EndUser' from dual;

create or replace function f_is_end_user (par_app_user in varchar2)
  return boolean
is
  l_one number(1);
begin
  select max(1) 
    into l_one
    from users
    where username = par_app_user
      and user_role = 'EndUser';
  return l_one = 1;
end;
/
```

Testing:

```
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line(case when f_is_end_user('&par_app_user') then 'it is end user'
  3                              else 'it is NOT end user'
  4                         end);
  5  end;
  6  /
Enter value for par_app_user: Little
it is NOT end user

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> /
Enter value for par_app_user: Foot
it is end user

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Create the same function for Admin users.

Now, go to Shared components, Authorization schemes, and create a new scheme:

- name it "end_user"
- type: PL/SQL function returning Boolean
- function body: `return f_is_end_user(:APP_USER);`
- error message: "You aren't authorized to do that."

Do the same for "admin" users.

Back to your application. Navigate to page and set its **Authorization Scheme**.

- for example, if you don't want to let end users view the page, set it to `{Not end_user}`
- You can do that for any item as well; if you don't want to let end users use the "Save" button, you'd modify button's "Authorization Scheme" property.

Quite easy, isn't it?

Comment: How about log in page? When I added code based on [this link]( https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/custom-authentication-and-authorization-using-built-in-apex-access-control-a-how-to), I can log in but can not set your suggestion. I added user_role  as a variable but somehow it errors.

Comment: What about log in page?

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I added one variable and change some codes based on yours! then everything is fine Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad if it helped. Though, I noticed that you do **not** upvote nor accept any answers that help you solve problems here. That discourages people to help you any further.

Comment: aha, did you still need help or did Littlefoot's answer sufficient? If it was, please accept his answer.